# Unclear about use of undefined SDK enum constants at runtime

Tags: constants, backwards-compatibility, compile-time-constant, runtime-environment

It might be best to start with an example: In OS X the following enum constants are defined in Foundation/NSString.h:

```
    NSCaseInsensitiveSearch = 1,
    NSLiteralSearch = 2,
    NSRegularExpressionSearch NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_7, 3_2) = 1024
```

Questions:

- At compile time, does the compiler simply replace NSRegularExpressionSearch with its constant value (1024)?
- Or, is the constant value found at runtime, and if so, then what value is the constant when running on pre 10.7?
- Is it advisable conditionally check at runtime what environment the program is running in before using the enum constant?
- Is it always safe to put `NSRegularExpressionSearch` in my code even if it will run on a pre-10.7 runtime? (By safe I mean the presence of the constant alone won't cause a crash or exception; obviously I must account for the program's behavior when I use a constant value that an older API doesn't recognize.)